# R: efficient computation of permutations of partitions

Tags: r, algorithm, permutation, partitioning

Given a vector containing `n` unique elements:

```
x <- c('a','b','c')
```

I would like to find all permutations of all partitions of `x` for arbitrary `n`. For `n=3` this means 13 orderings:

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a') ('b','c')
('b','c') ('a')
('a','b') ('c')
('a','c') ('b')
('b') ('a','c')
('c') ('b','a')
('a') ('b') ('c')
('a') ('c') ('b')
('b') ('a') ('c')
('b') ('c') ('a')
('c') ('a') ('b')
('c') ('b') ('a')
```

The partitions can be found using `listParts` from the `partitions` library (`setparts` unfortunately does not seem to be compatible with recent versions of R), and the permutations with `permn` from the `combinat` package:

```
library(partitions)
library(combinat)
parts <- listParts(length(x))

p1 <- permn(parts[[1]])
p2 <- permn(parts[[2]])
...
```

However, I am having difficulty finding an efficient means of permuting the partitions and storing the results. My goal is to map the results to a structure like

```
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 2
3 2 1 1
4 1 1 2 
...
```

where the integers indicate the order of the elements in the permutation. Since the partitions are internally unordered, any elements in a partition will receive the same integer rank. It seems there should be some way to do this efficiently by referencing the list index of the partition, but I can't sort out a way to do this.

Comment: It turns out this quantity has its own appellation, the Fubini number (https://oeis.org/A000670), which can quickly be found in R for a set of `n` elements using `sum(factorial(unlist(lapply(partitions::listParts(n), length))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is short snippet that will give the desired outcome:

```
x <- c('a','b','c')

## Probably not a good idea to name this parts as there
## is a function in the partitions package called parts
myParts <- partitions::listParts(length(x))

permParts <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(x), function(j) {
    tempParts <- myParts[lengths(myParts) == j]
    perms <- combinat::permn(j)

    unlist(lapply(tempParts, function(p) {
        lapply(perms, function(q) {
            t <- lapply(p[q], function(i) x[i])
            class(t) <- c("list", "equivalence")
            t
        })
    }), recursive = F)
}), recursive = F)
```

Here is the output with the given example:

```
permParts
[[1]]
[1] (a,b,c)

[[2]]
[1] (a,c)(b)

[[3]]
[1] (b)(a,c)

[[4]]
[1] (a,b)(c)

[[5]]
[1] (c)(a,b)

[[6]]
[1] (b,c)(a)

[[7]]
[1] (a)(b,c)

[[8]]
[1] (a)(b)(c)

[[9]]
[1] (a)(c)(b)

[[10]]
[1] (c)(a)(b)

[[11]]
[1] (c)(b)(a)

[[12]]
[1] (b)(c)(a)

[[13]]
[1] (b)(a)(c)
```

I wouldn't say the above is necessarily the most efficient solution, but I can't think of a more efficient attack without rolling your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! This is related to, but mildly more efficient than the solution I eventually came up with, which involved iteratively appending a list rather than the more efficient combination of `unlist` and `lapply`.